# What's a great site for managing contacts?

Tags: webapp-rec, contacts, google-contacts

At the moment I have all my contacts synchronized between Outlook and Gmail, but Gmail Contacts lacks some useful information.

So now I'm looking for a great site/web app for managing all my contacts.

Preferably it could sync with either Outlook or Gmail, but an export would be sufficient. 
Integration with other social sites for drawing in info would be a plus.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easyer way! And yes, I tried Soocial and Plaxo wich did not work as I likes and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your Outlook contacts synced using one of the provided applications to that service. They will then sync their server with Google and you get all of your contacts :)

This service also supports syncing your contacts from Facebook, LinkedIn and most other contact, calander online stores so you have a single point of truth that can sync with your phone, outlook and other services.

I also have it syncing in contacts from Plaxo and Soocial along with a plethera of other sites and apps.

Comment: Liking this one a lot, it has an overkill choice of features and sync with absolutely EVERYTHING!

Comment: On second hand, be wary to start syncing (both directions) from multiple clients. I ended up with 2000 contacts, creating up to 6-8 duplicates in each of my main clients (phone + outlook + gmail)... Sadly their interface isn't really 'smooth' for merging these

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following services:

- [**Soocial**](http://www.soocial.com/)
- [**Plaxo**](http://www.plaxo.com/)

Comment: I hadn't heard of Soocial before you mentioned it.  Have you used it?  If so, what do you think of it?

Comment: Soocial is still in Beta. I used it a while ago, and I was generally satisfied. There are some known issues which they give on their site. Check it out: http://www.soocial.com/support/known-issues

Answer (score 1):

**What was gmail choking on for you?  My only beef so far has been that it downgrades the quality of my contact pictures, but since most other solutions don't even sync them, I'm happy enough.**

**I think Google contacts is great, particularly if you use gmail or  have an iphone:**

- It's free
- It's accessible from anywhere, and well integrated into gmail, etc.
- It syncs seamlessly with the iphone in the cloud without connecting to your computer.   (I use Microsoft ExchangeSync settings)

The iphone sync works really well for me. I actually pay for MobileMe, and still use Google for my contact syncing.

Comment: I want to add in more information, especially about family and the address info for instance isn't really on the same level as Outlooks format

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many of your existing contacts are on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com), that might be a good option for you. They offer integration with Outlook if you need it.

[Plaxo](http://www.plaxo.com) is another, and if you're a Comcast high-speed internet subscriber, you don't have to pay for features like duplicate contact merging.  My own experience with them is that their calendar syncing never worked quite right on the Mac.  Since I switched to Verizon FIOS recently, I ended up getting rid of Plaxo and going with Google Sync for my contact info.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the iPhone, a mobile me account is pretty awesome.  Basically, you can update your contacts on your phone, pc, or Mac and they will all sync up and be on your phone and anyone else's phone that uses the same mobile me account (like your spouse).

If you aren't using an iPhone then Soocial is probably your best bet.  I think Plaxo is dieing down some but I always find it annoying because other people who have it request me to update my info with them.  So basically it will annoy your friends, family, and business associates that don't use it themselves.

Comment: One thing to note, the reason why most of these systems aren't great is because for them to be truly useful everyone would need to choose 1 or they would all need to have a common API and all talk to each other.  Unfortunately, neither of those things is going to happen anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

[Batchbook](http://www.batchblue.com/) is great and it integrates with many other web apps. It isn't free but the worth it for a business.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly a web app but there's a Firefox add-in to manage contacts

[Mozilla Contacts Add-On](http://mozillalabs.com/blog/2010/03/contacts-in-the-browser/)

It's in alpha at the moment, but shows promise.  Syncs contacts between Gmail, Twitter, LinkedIn etc. and autocompletes on any webpage where you start typing a name

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but I stumbled upon this service a couple of days ago, maybe it is worth a look

http://www.addressbookone.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use Highrise from 37signals for all my contact management needs.  Not perfect but I use it specifically to allow me to keep a history of interaction with a contact.

http://highrisehq.com/